# How do I give my container a static ip address (systemd-nspawn)

Tags: systemd, ip, systemd-networkd, container, systemd-nspawn

My container changes its ip address extremely often, almost every boot. I tried giving it a static ip address so my script knows how to ssh into it but nothing I did seemed to work. So I tried looking into the host side. No luck either. After doing the below (and rebooting my system). I tried booting with `-b -D path -n`. When I do I get 0 connectivity. `systemctl list-units --type=service` show systemd-networkd.service as `loaded active running`. I'm not sure what could be wrong. The container is alpine and the host is arch

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network /etc/systemd/network/
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have exactly the same problem.